# SSIS package truncating nvarchar field when outputting data

Tags: ssis

I have a Demographics table with this field: birth_datetime(nvarchar(19)null)

The values are character fields stored like this example value: '1946-06-16 00:00:00'

Even though this field is a character, my SSIS package is outputting the field as '00:00:00.0000000'

Any suggestions for troubleshooting my ssis package? Thank in advance!

Comment: In your data flow task check the output data type, it may be changing it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Where are you viewing your output?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out since the length of the field changed in the table I needed to go into the Data Flow and re-map the columns, in both the OLE DB Source and the Output file